# AWS Route 53 Alias record that can point to correct environment resources based on origin domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Is it possible to have an alias record where it can route into different environment resources using the domain origin?

We have this particular use case:

```
A client has 1 endpoint: 
https://assets.example.com
```

Backend has multiple env and version of assets that change dynamically:

```
Dev-assets-bucket -> version_1, version_2, version_3_latest
Prod-assets-bucket -> version_1, version_2,version_3_latest
```

We already have cloudfrount distribution thats pointing to the latest version deployed on each environment.

Ideally, we just want to give 1 endpoint to our client for their dev and prod. So in short,
their domain would be:

```
https://dev.example.io -> will be using https://assets.example.com
https://prod.example.io -> will also be using https://assets.example.com
```

Then serve the correct assets base on the domain origin that was detected.

Is this something possible to do in aws?

Comment: You can use CNAME or alias, but your server needs to be aware of this and support the two domains.

Comment: What if I don't pass it to a server? Ideally, should fetch from S3 bucket directly

Comment: Then S3 needs to be aware of that domain. Route 53 just converts a domain to IP. It can't affect the content retuned by your server whether it's your own EC2 or S3.